# Run all tests with coverage not showing

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, junit5

We are currently learning about unit testing in IntelliJ but I am running into the issue that I am missing something.

Taking the following video as an example (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QDFI19lj4OM), at 5.09, you see the option "*Run 'All Tests' with coverage*".

[image: screenshot at 05:10]

This option is missing in IntelliJ for me.

I've tried searching using google but I can't find the solution to this. All I get using google are links to tutorials where this option is being used.

I don't know if it matters but I am using Maven and JUnit 5.

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you add your test file here?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that something went wrong during my installation of IntelliJ. I had to manually add the plugin coverage and restart IntelliJ (did not know this was a plugin).

Comment: Please, share what plugin it was.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch to JUnit 4 to check if "Run 'All Tests" is there.

BTW, please you right click on test or project folder instead of main/java.

Comment: Does not seem to make a difference. There also should not be anything wrong with the test cases (2). Both do work from the cmd-line using mvn test.